# What would happen if I mix salt and sugar in a cup of water?

Tags: physical-chemistry, aqueous-solution, solutions

If I mix water in a cup with sugar at some stage the solution will become saturated and no more sugar will dissolve into the water. If I now add salt to the solution will the salt dissolve into the water or is the solution already saturated?

I have not tried an experiment as I cannot figure out how to measure the dissolved component of the 2, intuitively I think that some salt will dissolve, but not as much as in a pure salt water mixture.

Comment: Unfortunately, sugar is very soluble in water and will make a thick syrup (i.e. karo syrup) before you reach saturation.